# Answer list in R/exams distributed by several columns to save paper space

Tags: latex, r-exams

I would like to configure the answer list in R/exams to be distributed by columns:

A. Answer 1.    C. Answer 3.

B. Answer 2.    D. Answer 4.

In LaTeX, I have used the `multicol` package. Is that possible with R/exams as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The R/exams interfaces intended for producing PDF files for printing on paper are `exams2pdf()` and `exams2nops()` (which is built on top of `exams2pdf()`). Both of these use LaTeX in the background and allow to tweak the environment that is used for rendering the answer list. So the answer is: Yes, you can also use `{multicols}` environment from the `multicol` LaTeX package for this.

More specifically, in the LaTeX code your answer list will be written as:

```
\begin{answerlist}
  \item Answer 1.
  \item Answer 2.
  \item Answer 3.
  \item Answer 4.
\end{answerlist}
```

The rendering of this `{answerlist}` then depends on the definition of this environment in the header of the document. The default in `exams2nops()` as well as the demo templates for `exams2pdf()` shipped along with the package is:

```
\newenvironment{answerlist}%
  {\renewcommand{\labelenumii}{(\alph{enumii})}\begin{enumerate}}%
  {\end{enumerate}}
```

In short, this simply uses the standard `{enumerate}` environment and switches the counter to `(\alph{...})` formatting, i.e., (a), (b), .... In `exams2nops()` this yields the following output by default:

[image: default answerlist]

Alternatively, you can (re-)define this environment in the following way which uses a `{multicols}{2}` layout and switches the formatting of the counter to A., B., ...

```
\newenvironment{answerlist}%
  {\renewcommand{\labelenumii}{\Alph{enumii}.}\begin{multicols}{2}\begin{enumerate}}%
  {\end{enumerate}\end{multicols}}
```

When you are using `exams2pdf()` you can simply define the `{answerlist}` environment like this in the LaTeX master template that you pass to `exams2pdf(..., template = ...)`.

And when you are using `exams2nops()` you can re-define the `{answerlist}` environment on-the-fly in the `header`:

```
multicol <- "\\renewenvironment{answerlist}{\\renewcommand{\\labelenumii}{\\Alph{enumii}.}\\begin{multicols}{2}\\begin{enumerate}}{\\end{enumerate}\\end{multicols}}"
exams2nops(..., header = multicol)
```

This yields:

[image: answerlist with multicols]

Depending on the typical length of the items in your answer list you might, of course, also use more columns, e.g., `{multicols}{4}`.

Furthermore, there is also the built-in option `exams2nops(..., twocolumn = TRUE)` that switches the layout of the entire document to two columns (as opposed to only the answer list). A demo screenshot is included below.

Finally, some more variations that use the LaTeX environments `{paralist}` or `{enumitem}` instead of `{multicols}` are discussed in this thread in the R/exams forum on R-Forge: https://R-Forge.R-project.org/forum/forum.php?thread_id=33823&forum_id=4377&group_id=1337.

[image: twocolumn option for entire document]

Comment: Perfect, Achim! Thanks!